# React Native setState() warning on unmounted component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm getting the warning "setState(...): can only update a mounted or mounting component." if I navigate away from the screen containing this component and then navigate back to it and try to send a message. I've read some of the other SO posts with similar problems, but they all tend to be about removing listeners for asynchronous callbacks. The code causing the problem here is in the sendMessage() function, there's no callbacks.

I'm not clear on why my component isn't re-mounted. What am I doing wrong here?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  View
} from 'react-native';

class MessageEntry extends Component {  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      content: ''
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TextInput ref="newMessageContent"
          style={styles.input}
          multiline={true}
          placeholder="Ask me anything! :-)"
          onChangeText={(content) => this.setState({content: content})}
          value={this.state.content}
        />

        <Text onPress={() => this.sendMessage(this.props.chatRef)} style={styles.button}>Send</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }

  sendMessage(chatRef) {
    if (this.state.content == '') { return false; }
    chatRef.push({
      content: this.state.content,
      sent_at: Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
      self: true
    });

    this.setState({content: ''});
  }

}

export { MessageEntry }
```

Answer (score 0):

Props are immutable in React.  You're passing a prop to your sendMessage function and then modifying it.

Modifying those props causes the component to unmount and then a new instance of the component is mounted with the new props.  This all happens before the final setState in sendMessage.  So when you reach that setState, you're attempting to modify the recently unmounted version of the component.

Try loading `chatRef` into your state within the constructor.  Then have all subsequent references to chatRef pull from the state instance rather than the props, and be sure to only modify it with `setState` calls.